# Binding sometimes fails, depending on position of {Binding} in XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My program contains several instances of this line:

```
<local:MyClass Data="{Binding}"/>
```

I.e. the property `Data` is bound to the data context of the surrounding window. When the value of the window's `DataContext` changes, the binding is sometimes updated, sometimes not; it depends on the position of `<local:MyClass...>` in the XAML file.

Here is an example (**EDIT:** I changed the `{Binding}` to `{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=myWindow}` to emphasise that the problem is not related to inheritance of `DataContext`):

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="BindTest.MainWindow"
        x:Name="myWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindTest"
        Title="Binding Test" Height="101" Width="328">
    <Window.Tag>
        <local:MyClass x:Name="bindfails" Data="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=myWindow}"/>
    </Window.Tag>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Margin="5" Padding="5" Click="SetButtonClicked">Set DataContext</Button>
        <Button Margin="5" Padding="5" Click="ReadButtonClicked">Read Bound Property</Button>
        <local:MyClass x:Name="bindworks" Data="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=myWindow}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C# code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace BindTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SetButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = 1234;
        }

        private void ReadButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string txtA = (bindfails.Data == null ? "null" : bindfails.Data.ToString());
            string txtB = (bindworks.Data == null ? "null" : bindworks.Data.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("bindfails.Data={0}\r\nbindworks.Data={1}", txtA, txtB));
        }
    }

    public class MyClass : FrameworkElement
    {
        #region Dependency Property "Data"

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion
    }
}
```

First press button "Set DataContext" to change the data context. Then press button "Read Bound Property", which display this message:

> bindfails.Data=null
>
> bindworks.Data=1234

Obviously, the data binding was only updated for the `MyClass` element that is child of the `StackPanel`; but the data binding was not updated for the `MyClass` element that is referenced by `Window.Tag`.

**EDIT2:** I also have found out that binding works when adding the binding programmatically inside `MainWindow`'s constructor:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("DataContext") {Source = this};
bindfails.SetBinding(MyClass.DataProperty, binding);
```

The binding only fails when it is declared in XAML. Furthermore, the problem is not specific to `DataContext`; it also happens when I use other `Window` properties, such as `Title`.

Can anyone explain this behavior and suggest how to allow the use of `{Binding}` in XAML in both cases?

**EDIT3:** The above code is not entirely equivalent to the {Binding} markup extension. The 100% equivalent code is:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("DataContext") {ElementName = "myWindow"};
bindfails.SetBinding(MyClass.DataProperty, binding);
```

When I use that code, binding also fails (like when binding in XAML) and the following diagnostics message is written to debug output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=myWindow'.

Obviously, the `ElementName` property only searches up the visual tree or logical tree, even though this is not documented in the WPF online documentation. Probably, there is no easy way to set such a binding in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataContext is passed only throught the Object Tree. The Property tag is not in the visual tree and will not respond to DataContext changed Event and the binding is not refreshed without this event.

See : 
Dependency property identifier field: DataContextProperty from the FrameworlElement

Data context is a concept that allows objects to inherit binding-specifying information from their parents in the object tree

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I have searched the MSDN documentation for "data context"/"data binding" and "visual tree", but found no article that mentions that visual tree and data binding are correlated in any way. Where in the Microsoft documentation did you find the information that the data context can only be bound to inside the visual tree?

Comment: I Correct my post, is not the Visual Tree but the Object tree. The tag propertie is not part of this tree. I got the ref.

Comment: But the problem also happens with other properties than `DataContext`, such as `Title` (see my EDIT2 above); therefore I do not think that it has to do with inheritance in the object tree. After all, I am using `Binding.ElementName` to specify the binding source; I am not using any inherited property. Furthermore, if it really were related to the object tree, then it also would not work when I specify the binding programmatically; but it works when doing it programmatically (see also my EDIT2).

Comment: Even though your answer does not explain the reason for my problem, I will accept your answer because it led me on the right track (see my **EDIT3** above).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it does not work because when you write `{Binding}`, the context of the data to be bound is inherited from the parent. In case of bindworks, it's a `StackPanel`, which inherits `DataContext` from `Window`, however `bindfails.Parent` property is `null`.

I wonder why have you put a control in Window's tag element. If you must keep it declared in `Tag` node for some reason, you can update its `DataContext` directly, so just change `SetButtonClicked` method to:

```
private void SetButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = 1234;
    bindfails.DataContext = DataContext;
}
```

Another simple method to make it work is just taking `bindfails` out of `Window.Tag` and placing it somewhere in the `Window`, i.e. in the `StackPanel`. 
Next, in the Window's constructor, write `this.Tag = bindfails`. If you don't want the TextBox to appear in the form, you can set its `Visibility` to `Collapsed` (or put it inside a collapsed container control).

Comment: Using Window.Tag is just an example to demonstrate that {Binding} sometimes does not work; my actual program is much more complex. Setting "bindfails.DataContext" directly is not possible in the actual program. The problem is not related to inheritance; I will update my question to emphasise this.

Comment: When you put element in Window.Tag, binding to another element by its name seems not to work, but there are some workarounds (like a second solution suggestion in my answer), which can be different depending on a specific case.